# Is it possible to compile a static library with an external dependancy that is unresolvable at compilation time?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking

I've created a web server using C and C++, which works in the following way:

- First, it initialize the socket for the connection.
- Then, when the server receives an HTTP request, it calls a function that will retrieve the data form the request, and create an object which will parse the incoming request. (The object contains the request's parameters and headers).
- Then, it calls a function named HandleRequest, and gives him the object created. The object's type is `Request`, which I wrote myself.
- The HandleRequest function will analyze the request, generate an HTML document, and returns the whole document as a string.
- Finally, The server takes the string returned by the HandleRequest function and send it back to the client.

Now, if I want to create another site, the only code I will have to changed is the HandleRequest function.

My point is I want to pack the server itself in a static library, and then when I want to make a new website, I only have to write the HandleRequest function and link the static library when compiling to make the server.

Of course, when I try to do so, I have the error
`undefined reference to 'HandleRequest'`

So is it possible to make the library compile, knowing that a function has its code written outside of the library ?

Edit: I tried to compile the .cpp file with without the `-c` option, so that the library already have the linking done. I am aware that with the `-c` option, everything works fine.

Also, I tried to put 
`extern std::string HandleRequest(Request request);`
before the function that calls HandleRequest but it didn't worked.

Comment: I'm not a server guy but I wonder if you could accomplish this with a friend function for the HandleRequest...?  Others may know better

Comment: No problem getting it to compile.  You need to get it to link.  For which you need that "external library".  Be sure to pay attention to the error message you got.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "static library". If it's a `.lib` file, which is actually a set of (compiled) `.obj` files put together, there's no prob, you only need to link another object or library file containing the `HandleRequest` implementation in your project (or just implement it in your project and give it `extern` storage class). Even class member implementations ('definitions') can be contained in multiple source/object files. If you mean a statically linked dll, you need to define some callback mechanism or use a function pointer variable as suggested by @Jorge Perez.

Comment: The complete message error I got is ```undefined reference to `HandleRequest[abi:cxx11](Request)'```, and by "static library" I mean a ```.a``` file, like ```libws2_2.a```. If I compile the server lib with ```g++ -shared -fPIC <the source files> -o libserver.a```, I have the error, and if I use the method obtained from google (using the ```ar``` program of the GNU), then when linking the server lib with my implementation of HandleRequest, the executable is not is a correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quick and easy solution

Make `HandleRequest` a global variable that’s function pointer:

```
std::string (*HandleRequest)(Request);
```

You can move the functionality of the old `HandleRequest` function into something like `DefaultHandleRequest`, and you can even initialize the function pointer using the `DefaultHandleRequest`:

```
std::string DefaultHandleRequest(Request request)
{
    // stuff
}

std::string (*HandleRequest)(Request) = DefaultHandleRequest;
```

If you do this, you won’t have to change any other code, but you’ll be able to update `HandleRequest` whenever you like.

#### More thorough solution

We can make this solution much more general, enabling you to have multiple servers running in the same program.

In order to do this, make a `Server` class, which acts as the server. An instance of this class will act as your server. Have `Server` store a `std::function<std::string(Request)>` that handles incoming requests. You can assign or update this at any time, as necessary.

Design `Server` so that there can be multiple instances at once, each representing a different server/service with it’s own `HandleRequest` function.

Comment: I fail to see the issue. This addresses OP’s problem.

Comment: Whenever I read _"a global variable"_ that makes me _Shudder_, I can't help about that, sorry.

Comment: Oh XD yeah... that’s why I recommended the more thorough solution where OP encapsulates everything in a Server class

Comment: _Singleton Pattern_ would leave me shuddering less, but still concerned ;-).

Comment: Not using a singleton. Whenever OP wanted to start a new server they’d just create a new Server object, and there could be multiple Server objects, each with their own HandleRequest function

Comment: Making HandleRequest a function pointer is the closest from what I want to do (and it's what I'll keep if I can't do it the way I want). The class is good too but requires more code and work. These are good work-arounds, but I think they don't really answer my question which is compiling a static lib when one of the function doesn't have its implementation inside the library ?